# OpenKinect: Cannot build RGBDemo

Tags: opencv, makefile, cmake, computer-vision, openkinect

I am following the instructions given in the book ["Hacking the Kinect" pages 15-16 (Apress 2011)](http://books.google.de/books?id=IftkzqRjbO4C&lpg=PP1&dq=hacking%20the%20kinect&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q=hacking%20the%20kinect&f=false) to install the [RGB Demo](http://labs.manctl.com/rgbdemo/) (version 0.5.0) on my system (32bit x86 machine running Xubuntu 12.04).

I downloaded and extracted the demo's source and installed the needed packages as described within the book:

libboost-all-dev, libusb-1.0-0-dev, libqt4-dev, libgtk2.0-dev, cmake, ccmake (from cmake-curses-gui), libglew1.5-dev, libgsl0-dev, freeglut3-dev (**not** libglut3-dev as stated in the book), and libxmu-dev.

**Note book typo:** libgs10-dev should actually read libgsl0-dev.

When running ccmake on the source's root directory, I set the flags as given by the book:

- BUILD_EXAMPLES **ON**
- BUILD_FAKENECT **ON**
- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS **ON**
- NESTK_USE_FREENECT **ON**
- NESTK_USE_OPENNI **OFF**
- NESTK_USE_PCL **OFF**

and leave all other flags as their defaults.

I then proceed to configure and generate without issue, but when subsequently running make, I run into the following error:

```
[ 35%] Building CXX object nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/out.o
In file included from /home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/src/precomp.hpp:55:0,
                 from /home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/src/out.cpp:43:
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:354:13: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
In file included from /home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/src/precomp.hpp:55:0,
                 from /home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/src/out.cpp:43:
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2600:13: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2623:24: error: declaration of ‘operator[]’ as non-function
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2623:22: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2623:34: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘i’
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2626:36: error: declaration of ‘operator+=’ as non-function
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2626:32: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2626:46: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ofs’
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2628:36: error: declaration of ‘operator-=’ as non-function
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2628:32: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2628:46: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ofs’
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2641:5: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2642:15: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ has not been declared
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2661:13: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2684:21: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ has not been declared
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2687:37: error: declaration of ‘operator+=’ as non-function
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2687:33: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2687:47: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ofs’
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2689:37: error: declaration of ‘operator-=’ as non-function
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2689:33: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2689:47: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ofs’
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2733:22: error: declaration of ‘operator[]’ as non-function
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2733:20: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2733:32: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘i’
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2736:32: error: declaration of ‘operator+=’ as non-function
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2736:28: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2736:42: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ofs’
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2738:32: error: declaration of ‘operator-=’ as non-function
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2738:28: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2738:42: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ofs’
In file included from /home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4047:0,
                 from /home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/src/precomp.hpp:55,
                 from /home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/src/out.cpp:43:
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:2822:15: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:3383:31: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
In file included from /home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4048:0,
                 from /home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/src/precomp.hpp:55,
                 from /home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/src/out.cpp:43:
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1629:57: error: declaration of ‘operator+=’ as non-function
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1629:57: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1629:57: note: suggested alternatives:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h:156:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h:156:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
/home/josh/dev/kinect/RGBDemo-0.5.0/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/src/out.cpp:305:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
make[2]: *** [nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/out.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is causing these errors and how do I resolve them?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be as simple as `opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp` missing `#include <stddef.h>`?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just edit the `core.hpp /home/linaro/Downloads/RGBDemo-0.4.0-Source/nestk/deps/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core` and add the line

```
#include <stddef.h
```